# Add new (shorter) column to tibble and expand tibble to remain tidy

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe and I need to add a column to include 3 species that correspond to each row of the existing dataframe. Hopefully the example below makes it clear:

```
Site    Year    Trt
A       2016    bowl
A       2016    vane
A       2017    target
A       2017    stick
B       2016    bowl
B       2016    vane
B       2017    target
B       2017    stick

species<-c("species1", "species2", "species3")
```

Then I want to get to

```
Site    Year    Trt     Species
A       2016    bowl    species1
A       2016    vane    species1
A       2017    target  species1
A       2017    stick   species1
A       2016    bowl    species2
A       2016    vane    species2
A       2017    target  species2
A       2017    stick   species2
A       2016    bowl    species3
A       2016    vane    species3
A       2017    target  species3
A       2017    stick   species3
B       2016    bowl    species1
B       2016    vane    species1
B       2017    target  species1
B       2017    stick   species1
B       2016    bowl    species2
B       2016    vane    species2
B       2017    target  species2
B       2017    stick   species2
B       2016    bowl    species3
B       2016    vane    species3
B       2017    target  species3
B       2017    stick   species3
```

I guess some `rep` methods would be okay, but the real dataset has two additional columns and 141 species. I get paranoid about everything matching up right.

Comment: How is the tibble supposed to know how many times to repeat the species value? It it supposed to reset at each "bowl" value? It's unclear exactly how you want this to work.

Comment: @MrFlick It would appear that after a battery of `bowl, vane, target, stick` for each site, a new species is generated. Perhaps the easiest thing would be to split the data by site and apply the logic of species appearing for 4 entries each. But I agree, some further clarification, attempts and reproducible example would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using `tidyr::expand` to expand the data as:

```
library(tidyverse)
expand(data, nesting(Site, Year, Trt), species) %>% as.data.frame()

#     Site Year    Trt  species
# 1     A 2016   bowl species1
# 2     A 2016   bowl species2
# 3     A 2016   bowl species3
# 4     A 2016   vane species1
# 5     A 2016   vane species2
# 6     A 2016   vane species3
# 7     A 2017  stick species1
# 8     A 2017  stick species2
# 9     A 2017  stick species3
# 10    A 2017 target species1
# 11    A 2017 target species2
# 12    A 2017 target species3
# 13    B 2016   bowl species1
# 14    B 2016   bowl species2
# 15    B 2016   bowl species3
# 16    B 2016   vane species1
# 17    B 2016   vane species2
# 18    B 2016   vane species3
# 19    B 2017  stick species1
# 20    B 2017  stick species2
# 21    B 2017  stick species3
# 22    B 2017 target species1
# 23    B 2017 target species2
# 24    B 2017 target species3
```

**Data**

```
data <- read.table(text = 
"Site    Year    Trt
A       2016    bowl
A       2016    vane
A       2017    target
A       2017    stick
B       2016    bowl
B       2016    vane
B       2017    target
B       2017    stick",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

species<-c("species1", "species2", "species3")
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution leveraging `rep` method:

```
transform(
    do.call('rbind', rep(list(df), length(species))), 
    Species = rep(species, each=nrow(df))
)

#   Site Year    Trt  Species
#1     A 2016   bowl species1
#2     A 2016   vane species1
#3     A 2017 target species1
#4     A 2017  stick species1
#5     B 2016   bowl species1
#6     B 2016   vane species1
#7     B 2017 target species1
#8     B 2017  stick species1
#9     A 2016   bowl species2
#10    A 2016   vane species2
#11    A 2017 target species2
#12    A 2017  stick species2
#13    B 2016   bowl species2
#14    B 2016   vane species2
#15    B 2017 target species2
#16    B 2017  stick species2
#17    A 2016   bowl species3
#18    A 2016   vane species3
#19    A 2017 target species3
#20    A 2017  stick species3
#21    B 2016   bowl species3
#22    B 2016   vane species3
#23    B 2017 target species3
#24    B 2017  stick species3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base-R` solution would be this (you can later `sort` based on `Site` column):

```
cbind(dat, Species = rep(species, each = nrow(dat)))

#    Site Year    Trt  Species
# 1     A 2016   bowl species1
# 2     A 2016   vane species1
# 3     A 2017 target species1
# 4     A 2017  stick species1
# 5     B 2016   bowl species1
# 6     B 2016   vane species1
# 7     B 2017 target species1
# 8     B 2017  stick species1
# 9     A 2016   bowl species2
# 10    A 2016   vane species2
# 11    A 2017 target species2
# 12    A 2017  stick species2
# 13    B 2016   bowl species2
# 14    B 2016   vane species2
# 15    B 2017 target species2
# 16    B 2017  stick species2
# 17    A 2016   bowl species3
# 18    A 2016   vane species3
# 19    A 2017 target species3
# 20    A 2017  stick species3
# 21    B 2016   bowl species3
# 22    B 2016   vane species3
# 23    B 2017 target species3
# 24    B 2017  stick species3
```